# Pass New Props To Components Created from a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure how to update props of components that are rendered by mapping through an array.

I have an array called names, which I map over to render a Panel component for each name. Each panel contains a chart component that creates a chart showing some data. The data for each chart is passed as a prop called "data" to each chart component. The data for each chart is stored in an array called chartData. Here's an example:

```
{
  names.map((name, index) => {
    return (
      <Panel key={index}>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <Chart data={chartData[index]} />
      </Panel>
    );
  });
}
```

What I'm not sure how to do is update the data for each Chart component without mapping over the names array again and re-rendering everything. Once the data updates, I'd like have the new data passed to each existing chart component somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: `update the data for each Chart component without mapping over the names array` - I'm not sure what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Once the data changes, I'd like to update the charts, but I want to do so without making a new chart with the new data; I want the old chart to show the new data. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: If you use PureComponent for your Panel class, the re-rendering should be fairly efficient.

Comment: Hi if you are using `Redux` in your project you can use the `reselect` library which will memoize your store: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Answer (score 1):

React uses the concept of virtual DOM to "smartly" re-render only what it needs to, so if you're worried about performances and unnecessary re-renders cause by react reacting to the changed `names` array and re-rendering everything, don't.

I can see that you provided a key, so that's all you will need for it to decide what to re-render, and what not to.

tl;dr : Don't worry, react is smart :)

Comment: The problem isn't performance related, it's that the library that I'm using to render the chart requires that new data be passed to the existing chart rather than creating an entirely new chart for the new data. I know that react will update the DOM efficiently, but my chart library needs the data updated.

Comment: is that library taking data from DOM rather getting it through function's arguments?